# Cannot resolve marklogic-service-api:1.8.0.3

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic

I faced a dependencies error. It shows cannot resolve `org.apache.nifi:nifi-marklogic-service-api : 1.8.0.3`

I've added the nar files in `nifi/lib`. But it still has this error. How can I resolve that?

Here is the error message when I trying to build the package using mvn clean install

```
Failure to find org.apache.nifi:nifi-marklogic-services-api:jar:1.8.0.3 in https://jcenter.bintray.com/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jcenter has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
```

Comment: double-check that all of the binaries have been placed in the `nifi/lib` dir and that file permissions allow read? Maybe update the question with the exact error message that you are seeing and a listing of the directory contents?

Comment: 1.8.0.3 doesn't look like a valid NiFi release, we usually just do x.y.z. Is it a typo or a custom build?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to consult with MarkLogic on this one because their [releases](https://github.com/marklogic/nifi/releases) appear to be entire custom NiFi builds and not just "NiFi bundles." That's a significant issue for us because 1.8.0.3 is not an official NiFi build, and we can't make realistically provide compatibility with their NARs because they haven't separated them out into their own build.

The error message you see above is caused by them not releasing their NARs and JARs to Maven Central.